# "Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'" al intentar importar pyaudio en Python

Tags: python, pip

Estoy intentando importar `pyaudio`.

Instalé `portaudio` con el comando:

```
brew install portaudio
```

e instalé `pyaudio` con `pip`.

Ahora intento importar `pyaudio` y python me muestra el error:

> Could not import the PyAudio C module '_portaudio'

¿Algún consejo?

Seguí la solución de [pyaudio could not import _portaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36681836/1983854) pero no funciona. Lo he desinstalado como tres veces y no funciona, ahora no puedo instalar pyaudio porque dice que falta pamaccore:

> fatal error: 'pa_mac_core.h'

- Version Python: 3.4
- Sistema operativo: Mac OSX el capitán

Comment: Te indica que no puede importar el módulo binario `_portaudio` de `PyAudio`. Este módulo se compila a partir del fuente en código C. Tiene que haberte dado un error la instalación de Pyaudio. Reinstala pyadudio o, mucho mejor, instálatelo con [conda](http://conda.io).

Comment: segui la solucion de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36681836/pyaudio-could-not-import-portaudio pero no funciona lo he desinstaladlo como 3 veces y no funciona ahora no puedo instalar pyaudio porque dice que falta pamaccore  fatal error: 'pa_mac_core.h'

Comment: Pero esas instrucciones son para linux, no para osx. Este error es de compilación al no encontrar un fichero *include*. La solución sería instalarte algún paquete `dev` de tu sistema y probar de nuevo. Pero te recomiendo no perder más tiempo y usar [conda](https://conda.io).